# How does Instagram achieve the bottom navigation with notifications when there's still no support lib for google's bottom navigation?

Tags: android, material-design, instagram, navigationbar

As far as I have figured, the google's recent bottom navigation bar is still a mystery with no official supporting library (if there's any, kindly let me know). I have come across some 3rd party libs such as [roughhike](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar), [aurelhubert](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation). Now I am wondering what Instagram or other top ranked apps are using and how they have achieved this as I can't find a clue whether they are using such 3rd party libs? Any referenced guide or answer would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think so that instagram use bottom Navigation as you can create that view with custom view in bottom and frameLayout in top, there is no need to use any library, but as google introduce all principle if any app want, can create own bottomNavigation or use any exists libs,

Comment: Thanks Shayan. Although it would always be nice to have an official support lib from google to implement notifications , etc without much hassle and something that you know it would be around.